# Strange situation with html5 video in rails3 project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, video, html

I'm trying to implement html5 video in rails3 project and I stuck in strange situation.
To show HTML5 videos on the user's page i added this code:

```
<!-- Video element -->
<video width="420" height="240" controls preload="metadata" poster="/images/video.jpg">
 <!-- Video sources -->
 <source src="/movies/video.ogv" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'>
</video>
```

First weird thing is that the browser has added to original requests "GET /users/1" the request like this "GET /users/null", but it should be "GET /users/1" because the current user has id=1. Then in the movie controller (show action) i added this code:

```
filename = Rails.root.join('public/videos/' + params[:id] + '.' + params[:format])
send_file filename, :type => 'video/ogg'
```

where params[:id] is the name of video file.
Everything seems alright, but i've got error:

```
ERROR Errno::ENOBUFS: An operation on a socket could not be performed 
because the system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full
```

Could you help me how to understand and resolve this thing? Thanks

Comment: Can't you just make the source tags src attribute point directly to the file in the public/videos/ directory?

Comment: I did, I changed 'movies' to 'video' then webserver treats it straightforward and i just got another error "ERROR Errno::ECONNABORTED: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine".

Comment: Having same issue as you trying to send a 140mb HTML5 video file over webrick with Rails 3. If I try to download http://127.0.0.1/video.webm the server keeps disconnecting it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Webrick doesn't support video streaming as far as I can tell. Try switching to passenger

Answer (score 1):

Can'e make sense of your first problem. For #2, try this:

```
send_file filename, :type => 'video/ogg', :disposition => 'inline'
```

Comment: Didn't help, maybe some problem with WEBrick server